# Solving the following limit

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

I need help solving $\lim _{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{4}{\theta^{2}} \int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} d t$.
I see through empirically plugging in numbers in software (using R's 'integrate' function and multiplying the retrieved value with $\frac{4}{\theta^{2}}$) that when $\theta \rightarrow-\infty$, the limit above converges to 2. However, I would like to know if there is a more concrete way to evaluate the said limit.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} dt=\lim_{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \int_{\theta}^{0} \frac{-t}{e^{t}-1} dt\leq\lim_{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \int_{\theta}^{0} \frac{-t}{-1} dt=-\infty$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} dt=-\infty$. So, we can apply L'Hospital's rule on the given integral.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\lim _{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{4}{\theta^{2}} \int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} d t=\lim _{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{4\displaystyle\frac{d}{d\theta}\bigg(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\theta} \frac{t}{e^{t}-1} dt\bigg)}{2\theta}=\lim _{\theta \rightarrow-\infty} \frac{4\displaystyle\frac{\theta}{e^{\theta}-1} }{2\theta}=-2$.

The required limit is thus $-2$.

Comment: Thank you for the indepth answer! It has been a while since i used integration so I am a bit rusty

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Hospital and FTC:

$\lim_{\theta \rightarrow -\infty} 4\frac{\left (\frac{\theta}{e^{\theta}-1}\right)}{2\theta}$.

Comment: and the fundamental theorem of calculus...

Comment: Yes. Thank you:)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate the hint

Comment: user_2.177. A pleasure.